# Binary search in a sorted list with all nodes as struct C++

Tags: c++, list, stl, binary-search

I have a list with all the elements as struct of form

```
typedef struct person_node{
    string name;
    string country;
}person;

std::list<person> list;
```

The list is already **sorted on person name**.

How do I use the inbuilt **binary_search()** function in this?

I already know how to use this **binary_search()** on a list with only numbers as data, but I wonder how can I use it for such a list.

I am using this binary function as:

```
binary_search (list.begin(), list.end(), value, compare_function);
```

Only thing I don't know is, "What should I enter in place of **value**, if I need to look for a specific name in the list?"

Also I want **an iterator** to point to that node, if found.

Comment: The value you are searching for. Since you didn't explain what you're searching for, I'm not sure what else we can tell you.

Comment: You should enter properly initialized `person_node`; `person_node Temp; Temp.name = "r20rock"; binary_search(l.begin(), l.end(), Temp, comp);`

Comment: Binary search on a **list** makes little sense (it makes sense only if the comparison of the keys is *very* expensive compared with the cost of transversing the list, which I doubt it is the case). The cost of finding the split point is linear on the size of the list, and requires visiting all previous nodes.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas ok, if I agree to use a **vector** for this, still how will I get the position of the node I am looking for?

Comment: @r20rock: If you use a `vector`, then the question makes more sense and you can use the approach that Jerry Coffin mentions in his answer (`std::lower_bound` or `std::upper_bound`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You enter a `person` containing the `name` you want to find.

Also note that `binary_search` is only rarely useful (it only tells you whether the item is present, not where it is in the collection. It is doubly useless on a `std::list`, because it requires random-access iterators to work at all well (which `std::list` doesn't provide).

So, what you probably want is an `std::vector<person>` or `std::deque<person>`, which you'll probably want to search with `std::lower_bound` or `std::upper_bound`. `std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound` will each return an iterator to the item they found, giving you access to that object.

Comment: @Jerryy Coffin ok, if I agree to use a vector for this, still how will I get the position of the node I am looking for?

Comment: @r20rock: If you use an std::vector with lower_bound or upper_bound, that'll return an iterator to the item it found.

Comment: ,One more doubt, how to use `lower_bound` when nodes are `struct`? what should be my 3rd argument?

Comment: @r20rock: Your third argument would be a `person` with its `name` set to the value you want to search for. You'll probably also need to pass the fourth argument, which will be a function (or functor) like `bool cmp(person const &a, person const &b) { return a.name < b.name; }` If you're using a new enough compiler, you probably want to write that as a lambda.

Answer (score 2):

The 3rd item describes what you are searching for in such a way that you can call

`compare_function(*iter, value )`

or

`compare_function( value, *iter )`

where `iter` is a valid iterator within your collection. This should return `true` in the first case if `*iter` must appear before `value` in your list for it to remain sorted, and in the second case vice versa.

Note, therefore, that you can actually pass in a `string` as the 3rd parameter if your `compare_function` supports both these overloads. The prototype is:

```
template <class ForwardIterator, class T, class Compare>
   bool binary_search ( ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last,
                   const T& value, Compare comp );
```

and it is not necessary that the T is the value type of the iterator.

Incidentally whilst you can use it for a `std::list`, it is extremely inefficient for iterators that are not random-access as each `std::advance` statement is `O(N)` thus the whole operation is `O(N log N)`. Even a regular `std::find` would be faster.

Use `vector` or `multiset` if you can have duplicates or `set` if you do not allow duplicates.

Also `binary_search` itself returns `true/false` as to whether the item exists and doesn't find you the item (so you won't know their country). If you have duplicates you can use `std::equal_range` to get a list of all such values. If you do not you can use `std::lower_bound` which will get you an iterator to the first item with a name equal to or greater than yours, then check if it is equal, rather than greater.

Comment: You can, actually, it supports bidirectional iterators. Not saying it's a good idea.

Comment: It supports bidirectional which means you can go forward or backward but cannot "jump" like you need to do with binary_search. If it uses `std::advance` to jump that is an O(N) operation for a list. Personally I'd rather it failed to compile to flag the poor use of STL by the user.

Comment: @CashCow ok, if I agree to use a vector for this, still how will I get the position of the node I am looking for?

Comment: You use std::lower_bound and that returns an iterator. You can first check if this is the "end" iterator in which case your item isn't found. Then check if the value matches what you are looking for. Then you know the item exists. To find out what position this is in the collection, subtract begin() (or use std::distance)